# android: Create new "default" content provider?

Tags: android

In Android, is it possible to create a "default" content provider?

Suppose I want to create my own contacts app that becomes the default contacts database.

Would I be able to create a content provider which would take the place of the place of the [default Contacts provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html)?

Alternatively, is it possible to be notified each time an app attempts to read the contacts database/provider?

Answer (score 2):

> Would I be able to create a content provider which would take the place of the place of the default Contacts provider?

Only by creating your own custom ROM. First one in wins; you cannot replace `com.android.contacts` (or whatever the stock Contacts app's authority string is) with your own implementation via an ordinary SDK app.

> is it possible to be notified each time an app attempts to read the contacts database/provider?

No.